# Typo3 Fluid: use TS-settings in configuration-tag

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I've got the paginationwidget

```
   <f:widget.paginate objects="{jobs}" as="paginatedJobs" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 4, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 1, addQueryStringMethod :{querystring : querystring}}">
```

And i want to insert the value of itemsPerPage via TypoScript, so i tried

```
{itemsPerPage: {settings.itemsPerPage}, insert....}
```

The Result is an Error:
The argument "configuration" was registered with type "array", but is of type "string" in view helper...

The same when i try to us it in the alias-Tag

```
<f:alias map="{number: {settings.itemsPerPage}}">
```

Is there a possibility to get it working? I need this value in my Controller so it should be the same in the template...

Comment: At least for the <f:alias> it should work with <f:alias map="{number: settings.itemsPerPage}">. The widget config might work this way as well (skip the {} around settings.itemsPerPage)

Comment: OMG only because of the {}! It works now in both cases, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer made from my comment, because it seems to work :)

At least for the `<f:alias>` it should work with `<f:alias map="{number: settings.itemsPerPage}">`.

The widget config might work this way as well. Sskip the **{...}** around settings.itemsPerPage.